# Reach static IP on a different subnet

Tags: networking, static-ip

I want to set a private IP to a Linux server located in my LAN.

I've used the following commands to set the IP to `192.168.10.100`:

```
sudo nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1" ipv4.method manual  
sudo nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1" ipv4.address 192.168.10.100/24
sudo nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1" ipv4.gateway 192.168.10.1
sudo nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1" ipv4.dns "1.1.1.1 192.168.10.1"
sudo nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1" autoconnect yes
sudo nmcli con down "Wired connection 1"
sudo nmcli con up "Wired connection 1"
```

This seems to work fine:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.10.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
    inet6 fe80::d5f3:f6d5:dbe8:b2e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2a01:cb08:87ea:1400:bb5e:dc6b:363b:871a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 2a01:cb08:87ea:1400:3942:9e91:3c69:c1d6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether 48:b0:2d:0f:17:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 179  bytes 44975 (44.9 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 145  bytes 15200 (15.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 41
```

When I try to connect to that IP through SSH, I got a timed out error.
I'm almost certain there is something to do with the subnet mask.

On my Windows computer, I've tried to run the following command to make the server reachable, but without success:

```
route add -p 192.168.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1
```

My Windows config:

```
Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : home
Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::2406:318c:2274:a5c0%24
Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.1.19
Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

How to make the server reachable from my LAN ?

Comment: It's not the subnet mask. Lose the route, it's incorrect and unnecessary. All traffic to `192.168.10.0/24`-net is sent to your gateway `192.168.1.1`. This router must be able to reach `192.168.10.1`. You need to configure into `.1.1` a route to forward traffic to `10.0/24` -net to the router `192.168.10.1`, and to `.10.1` you need to configure route towards `192.168.1.1` so it can route traffic back. If you'd be kind to add a topology map to your question it'd be a lot easier to help you resolve this.

Comment: If the two IP subnets actually resides in the same broadcast domain (with no VLAN whatsoever), what you need is a direct (i.e. gateway-less) route on *both* hosts for each other / each other's subnet. (Certainly you can make them one big subnet with `255.255.0.0` as the netmask on both hosts.)

Comment: Thing is, why even make use of `192.168.10.0/24` (instead of `192.168.1.0/24`) on the Linux server? (Does `192.168.10.1` even exist btw?)

Comment: @TomYan's very correct, but advice on a large subnet only applies if there is only one gateway router - different gateway IPs on both devices which are both declared to be working suggests there are 2. That said - the fact that `ifconfig` shows TX and RX packets means _only_ that there's a working physical and Layer 2 connection, but _not_ that there's an actual working IP connection. That's easy to test on the server with command `ping 192.168.10.1` - successful ping = functional IP connection.